Django not loading CSS (static files)
I'm a beginner to Django trying to apply a CSS file (stored in base/static/css) to the base page of a web app. For some reason the file is not applying to the page, and I'm getting an output of "GET /social/ HTTP/1.1" 200 29461 when I refresh the page. I've tried to apply other answers to the same issue, such as making sure django.contrib.staticfiles and my base folder socialnetwork are in INSTALLED_APPS, using STATICFILES_DIRS instead of STATIC_ROOT (in conjunction with using python manage.py collectstatic in terminal) or having them point in different folders, and putting
urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL,document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)

in my urls.py file, which worked once and then immediately went back to the same error (I also tried using staticfiles_urlpatterns() instead of this). After looking through the docs I tried disabling and clearing recent cache using Developer Tools in my browser, as well as manually restarting the server using Ctrl+C and python manage.py runserver, both not seeming to have an effect (although after deleting cache I did get a 404 error for some media files which cleared up quickly).
I did have a similar issue with loading in media files earlier, but this was fixed easily with
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL,document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)

which doesn't seem to be working here for static files.
My project uses runserver which from other answers it seems is not the best, though I'm only using this project locally on my PC. My files are as follows:
socialnetwork/landing/templates/base.html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/a3159a882f.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
    
    {% load static %}
    <link href="{% static 'css/style.css' %}" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">

    <title>Social Network</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    {% include 'landing/navbar.html' %}
    {% block content %}
    {% endblock content %}

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>

socialnetwork/socialnetwork/urls.py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('landing.urls')),
    path('accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),
    path('social/', include('social.urls')),
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL,document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)

Then in socialnetwork/socialnetwork/settings.py, I have
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'socialnetwork',
    'social',
    'static',
    'landing',
    'allauth',
    'crispy_forms',
    'crispy_bootstrap5',
    'allauth.account',
    'allauth.socialaccount',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    "django.contrib.sites",
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

and
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
]

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

with DEBUG = True.
For the page I'm rendering (post_list.html), the related views in socialnetwork/social/views.py return render(request, 'social/post_list.html', context). Finally, my file structure looks roughly like
social network
> landing
  -> templates
     -> base.html
> media
> social
  -> templates
     -> post_list.html
  -> models.py
  -> urls.py
  -> views.py
> socialnetwork
  -> settings.py
  -> urls.py
> static
  -> admin
  -> css
     -> style.css
> templates
> manage.py

Thank you for reading, I've tried to include anything I think is relevant. Is there a solution or something I've overlooked here?

put STATIC_ROOT setting in to settings.py file.
As below.
Collect

STATIC_ROOT = 'your collect static folder path relative to project folder'

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
]


